# Android: Remove app shortcut from home screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove app shortcut from home screen. Using this two actions:

1. `com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT`
2. `com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT`

It works perfect for me, but when I drag icon from apps list to home screen `UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT` doesn't work. So, is there any difference between this two methods and how the system behave in each situation?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void deleteShortCut(Context context) {

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.example.androidapp", "SampleIntent");
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("someParameter", "HelloWorld");

    Intent removeIntent = new Intent();
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "ShortcutName");
    removeIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

    removeIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");       
    context.sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't work for me. Imho InstallShortcutReceiver store some additional data  in LauncherModel when you send broadcast to create a shortcut, and when you just drag icon from list without sending broadcast system does something else. Any suggestions?

Comment: codinggeekorg.wordpress.com/tag/home-screen-shortcuts/#–                check this link maybe you get some help.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/how-can-i-remove-unwanted-app-icons-from-the-screen this one also.

Comment: you got some help from these links?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't.

Comment: you checked both links?

Comment: @vshpyrka http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-android-tips-and-tricks.htm  you have to check this link once.