# Removing an Android Shortcut from Home screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to remove a shortcut from  the home screen  that my app has already added. I have tried the methods in these links but I can't figure out how to adapt their solutions to my code. I dont have a rooted device so I cant find the URI.

https://codinggeekorg.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/android-home-screen-shortcuts-part-iii-remove-shortcuts/

[Trying to UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT but shortcut won't go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480287/trying-to-uninstall-shortcut-but-shortcut-wont-go-away)

[Android: Remove app shortcut from home screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957374/android-remove-app-shortcut-from-home-screen)

Here is where I create the shortcut:

```
        protected void  ShortcutCreatorActivity(String number, String message, String name) {
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShortCutActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        shortcutIntent.putExtra("number", number);
        shortcutIntent.putExtra("message", message);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, name);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.abezukor.autosms" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".RelativeLayoutActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ShortCutActivity"
        android:label="AutoSms">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.